# Observable.fromEvent is not a function in prod mode Angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6

I am working on angular project having one issue **Observable.fromEvent is not a function**. This issue arises in production build for angular 6. I am using rxjs version 6.2.2.

Response will be highly appreciated.

Comment: So have you actually migrated your code to RxJS 6?

Comment: Have a look at this: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md

Comment: yes migrated from angular 5 to angular 6. its working in development mode, error only arises when development mode.

Comment: Have you installed rxjs-compat npm package?

Comment: Yup its installed

Comment: @R.Richards I have followed that guide but facing the same error.

Comment: Can you remove node_modules and try these 2 commands 1) npm cache clean --force 2) npm install

Comment: @SureshKumarAriya still same one

Comment: Updated the answer. please check it works

Answer (score 3):

In RxJS 6, Observable.fromEvent() is been deprecated. instead use only fromEvent.

```
import { Observable, fromEvent } from 'rxjs';

keys$:Observable = fromEvent( document, 'keyup');
```

Comment: @SureshKumarAriyaI am not using this function in my code. Is it something to do with Http call?

Comment: Can you share through whole project codebase using VS Editor search. Might be some node_modules package might be using. please check.